# Is there a way to avoid code duplication caused by 'out of scope' error in C#?

Tags: c#, scope, goto

C# goto out of scope error means I have to duplicate code - is there a better way?

This is just a rough example, but there are often multiple statements that may fold into the same code and I don't want to repeat the code, for example:

```
            if (hasp1[0] == 2)
            {
                DialogMessageBox("test");
                ret=false;
                goto end1;
            }

            if (hasp1[0] == 3)
            {
                DialogMessageBox("test");
                ret = false;
                goto end1;
            }
```

I have cleanup going on at end1 that I want to always end with (maybe I should be using a finally block?)

Anyway, in C/C++ I can just add a label to the top one and use goto to go to it, but in C# it complains about them not being in the same scope.

I can somewhat solve that problem with this, but it is ugly:

```
    if (!(hasp1[0] == 2))
                goto skipz1;
            
                z1:
                DialogMessageBox("test");
                ret = false;
                goto end1;
            skipz1:

            if (hasp1[0] == 3)
            {
                goto z1;                    
            }
```

What are the better ways to do this?  Perhaps I have to pry goto from my fingers...

Comment: Hard to say what the best way to fix this without seeing the rest of the code.  However, I will say that in 15 years of C# coding, I don't think I've ever once needed to use a goto statement

Comment: Pro tip: do not use `goto`, end of story. Using it to jump to case blocks in a switch statement is cool but it quickly degrades readability when over abused

Answer (score 4):

Isolate this code (including anything not shown up to the label) in it's own method. Then, instead of `goto` to skip ahead, you can `return` from the method.

Separately, since the bodies of the conditional blocks are so similar, this could be reduced with an `||` operator:

```
if (hasp1[0] == 2 || hasp1[0] == 3)
{
     DialogMessageBox("test");
     ret=false;
}
```

You could also use a `switch` block to consolidate the code:

```
switch(hasp1[0])
{
    case 2:
    case 3:
        DialogMessageBox("test");
        ret=false; 
    break;
}
```

Or, if you have a lot of these, by looking in a collection:

```
int[] items = {2, 3};
if (items.Any(i => i == hasp1[0]))
{
     DialogMessageBox("test");
     ret=false;
}
```

C# also now has fancy `switch` expressions that might reduce this even more, but I'd want to know more of the surrounding code before suggesting exactly what that might look like.

The point is, there are *so many ways to do this* that don't involve `goto` at all.

Comment: I'd rather not return in the middle of a method for two reasons - (1) I prefer always returning at the end because it is more readable, and (2) I usually have something I want to cleanup.  Maybe I should probably use a finally block for that purpose instead of goto, though that doesn't really solve this question - avoiding duplicate code at different failure points.  Your idea of combining with an || is one I commonly use, but sometimes the two if's are in different places and can't be combined.  One thing I did was create a method inside the method and call it, but that doesn't feel elegant.